# how to model File output node on IBM RIT

Tags: automated-tests, ibm-rad

I synced an IIB node with RIT and deployed a flow which has MQInput and FileOutput nodes. Only MQInput node is recognized and synced by RIT, but not FileOutput. How do I make RIT recognize and sync FileOutput node so I can create test suites?
-J

Answer (score 1):

Jane,

As far as I remember RIT will be only able to recognize only queues because communication between Rational Integration Tester and IBM Integration Bus is performed using a WebSphere MQ queue manager.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.rit.integration.doc/topics/c_ritwmb_software_requirements.html

To solve your issue you will have to add FileOutput manually and create a listener for that.

Comment: How do I add FileOutput manually and create a listener for it?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBLQQ_8.5.0/com.ibm.rational.rit.files.doc/topics/c_ritfiles_file_trans.html